# Создание <thead> для нескольких таблиц

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт для создания < thead > внутри таблицы без такового тега.

```
var thead = $("#myid tr:first").html();
$("#myid tr:first").remove();
$("#myid").prepend('<thead>' + thead + '</thead>');
```

Однако на странице идет несколько таблиц с разными id и одним классом. Можно ли минимизировать код, чтоб избавится от необходимости его дублировать для каждой таблицы отдельно. Пример того, что есть сейчас:

```js
var thead = $('#myid1 tr:first').html();
var thead2 = $('#myid2 tr:first').html();

$('#myid1 tr:first').remove();
$('#myid2 tr:first').remove();

$('#myid1').prepend('<thead>' + thead + '</thead>');
$('#myid2').prepend('<thead>' + thead2 + '</thead>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myclass" id="myid1">
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name 1</th>
            <th>Name 2</th>
            <th>Name 3</th>
            <th>Name 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="myclass" id="myid2">
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name 1</th>
            <th>Name 2</th>
            <th>Name 3</th>
            <th>Name 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Банальный цикл можно использовать хотя бы.

```js
$('table.myclass').each(function(){
    var first = $(this).find("tr:first"), thead = first.html();
    first.remove();
    $(this).prepend('<thead>' + thead + '</thead>');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myclass" id="myid1">
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name 1</th>
            <th>Name 2</th>
            <th>Name 3</th>
            <th>Name 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="myclass" id="myid2">
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name 1</th>
            <th>Name 2</th>
            <th>Name 3</th>
            <th>Name 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
            <td>Val</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('table.myclass').prepend(function() {
  var first = $("tr:first", this);
  return $("<thead>", {
    html: first.html()
  }).replaceAll(first)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myclass" id="myid1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name 1</th>
      <th>Name 2</th>
      <th>Name 3</th>
      <th>Name 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="myclass" id="myid2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name 1</th>
      <th>Name 2</th>
      <th>Name 3</th>
      <th>Name 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```